What movie is this? (Frozen guy wakes up, thirsty: drinks from toilet)

Some guy fighting in a war with 'swords' gets injured(probably) and falls into the ice and gets frozen.
Some people uncover him in the present and keep him in sort of a box/crate/coffin
wakes up from an accidental electrical charge
He had long hair
In another part of the story, he's thirsty and doesn't know where to drink from, so he drinks the water from the toilet (can't confirm that this was from the same movie).
Later from a magazine (probably) realizes that toilets are meant for something else...

I saw this movie a long time ago and only a tiny part of it. I can't guarantee the accuracy of the events. Any clues or movie-names would be helpful. Thanks in advance.
Year I saw this: 2006-07
Colour: Yes

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.
